# Short story that had doors being replaced with portals in the future?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall a sci-fi story, likely a short story in a compendium, set in the future where portals are used to move about as the outside is believed to be uninhabitable due to fallout from a war. The portals are referred to as Doors with the emphasis on the capital 'D'. A child finds and uses a door, i.e. a physical opening doorway that leads outside and find the outside is pleasant.

Can anyone identify the story or even better, the book?

Comment: Reminds me of the [Farcasters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farcaster) from [Hyperion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_Cantos)...

Comment: A portal is fancy word for a fancy door, entrance, or gateway. Replacing doors with portals sounds like a movement toward imposing architecture. To what do the archictecturally imposing doors in this story which do not lead outside lead?

Comment: @DavidC "portal" has become a generic term in popular culture for sci-fi and magical surfaces that connect two nonadjacent locations directly (other sci-fi terms such as "wormhole" imply a particular mechanism, and there aren't any other generic fantasy terms, though there are often terms specific to a setting [such as Door here]), and it is pedantic and disingenuous to refuse to consider that meaning.

They haven't been replaced with websites either, I assume.

Comment: @Random832 Yes, I was being pedantic. My point was that the question is a little vague about where these portals lead. In sci-fi we have interdimensional portals, time portals, etc. I also found the description funny: Doors are replaced with portals which are called Doors.

Comment: Lookup the word "portal": a _door_ is a kind of _portal_.  You might want to add an adjective to point out that you're talking about a teleportation device.  https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20portal

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[*It's Such a Beautiful Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Such_a_Beautiful_Day) by Isaac Asimov.

A boy is forced to walk because their Door is broken, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you ! I read this many many moons ago and have had a nostalgic hankering to re-read it, Now I know the title I have a decent chance of finding it..

Comment: BTW - I don't recall any hint of a nuclear war in that story, it was simply that people (especially the kid's mother) had become accustomed to being shielded from 'bad things' outside like wind & rain, that she thought her son preferring to use the doors was nonsensical, and was worried he might be *afraid* to use the doors (if they fail between entry & exit point, what happens?). The outside world (gardens & such) was being beautifully tended & maintained by robots (a typical Asimov touch).

Comment: It could well be so many stories merging in my memory ! I may have assumed the reason they used the Door wasn't just lazyness etc.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If OP was reading a lot of Asimov at the time of reading this, it would be a very understandable error of recollection, as Asimov used that background in a lot of his works...

Comment: True, just thought I should point out the one significant difference in recollection.

Answer (score 39):

## [It's Such a Beautiful Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Such_a_Beautiful_Day) by Isaac Asimov

Everybody has a door in their house, and the main character's (a young boy, aged around 10-11) Door breaks. When he is forced to go outside using the little-d door, he finds he likes it.

It could have been in a bunch of different anthologies, the one I read it in and own it as is *[Nightfall and Other Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_and_Other_Stories)*.

[image: nightfall cover]

Comment: Dunno what you guys are talking about, but it doesn't seem to be on-topic or related to this answer, so I've [moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42012/discussion-on-answer-by-es-i-short-story-that-had-doors-being-replaced-w). Feel free to continue there! :-)

Comment: List of anthologies: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62723