# Short story where doors are used for teleportation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking to find a short story that has doors that teleport people from door to door instead of having to use the door to exit into the outside world.

Comment: There are many such stories. Can you narrow it down? I recall one such story with a woman and her son. One day the door at their house broke and he had to walk to his destination. Even after the door was fixed, he still tended to walk, and his mother became concerned that he was avoiding the doors for fear of them failing when he was 'mid door'. Eventually a psychologist(?) determined that the boy was simply loving the walk through environments now beautifully tended by robots.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. Can you provide more details, like when and where the story was published, when and where it was set, anything else that can narrow down the search?

Comment: See [Short story that had doors being replaced with portals in the future?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133731/short-story-that-had-doors-being-replaced-with-portals-in-the-future)

Answer (score 9):

The story identified by Andrew Thompson is **It's Such A Beautiful Day** by Isaac Asimov.

The household Door fails and the son takes a liking to being outdoors.  The psychologist recommend she not worry about it, once it loses its air of forbiddenness, the kid will likely lose interest.

The title comes from the closing line.  When the mother offers to dial up the Psychologist's destination, he declines, stating that he'll walk because "it's such a beautiful day."