# A story of a child who discovers the joy of walking to school

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation

Well, as the title suggests, it is a story where a child discovers the joy of walking to school.

This is a dystopic novel.

At their age, they use teleportation for their travel. They are very germophobic.

No one goes out of their houses physically.

One day, the said child goes off to school or returns, I don't remember because the teleportation thing was not working. Then he enjoys it and goes to school and returns back physically. Everyone is shocked (and disgusted, I guess?).

Well, that's the story. I have no idea when or where I read it.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133731/short-story-that-had-doors-being-replaced-with-portals-in-the-future/133732#133732

Comment: Suggested dupe target is excessively minimal, and even this question is better.  I'm going to vote to leave open, and regardless of the result of the vote I'm going to close the other way.  (Note that this is a simple pair, and there are no other questions that would need to be changed.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is [*It's Such a Beautiful Day*](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62723) by Isaac Asimov. First published in 1955 in [*Star Science Fiction Stories No. 3*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?32087), it's available to [read online](https://archive.org/details/bestscienceficti0000asim/page/200/mode/2up?q=It%5C%27s%20Such%20a%20Beautiful%20Day) thanks to the Internet Archive.

Summary per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Such_a_Beautiful_Day):

> Set in the year 2117, the story presents District A-3, a newly built suburb of San Francisco, and the world's first community to be built entirely using Doors, a method of travel via teleportation.
>
> When the Door that transfers him from home to school fails, Richard "Dickie" Hanshaw takes a dislike to the method and starts to wander outside in the unfamiliar open, exposed to the elements. When he catches a cold, Mrs. Hanshaw is horrified and takes him to see Dr. Sloane, a psychiatrist, afraid that her son's wanderings are signs of a mental abnormality.
>
> Despite his own misgivings, Dr. Sloane invites Dickie to go for a walk with him in the open, and Sloane learns to understand and appreciate the boy's dislike of moving around by matter transference and his newly acquired interest in the open air. Dr. Sloane advises Mrs. Hanshaw not to disapprove of Dickie's odd hobby so heavily, to treat it as if it is no big deal. This will remove its tantalizing aura of forbiddenness, and soon Dickie will lose interest in it and turn his attention to more "normal" interests.
>
> At the conclusion of his consultation with Dickie and Mrs. Hanshaw, Dr. Sloane succumbs to Dickie's viewpoint and says, "You know, it's such a beautiful day that I think I'll walk."

Comment: << Richard "Dickie" Hanshaw takes a dislike to the method >> Is that description quite accurate? From what I recall, he doesn't dislike Doors, and is happy to use them, it's that he likes walking outside.

Comment: @Pete - you’re right, the Wikipedia synopsis isn’t entirely accurate. From a brief scan of the story he’s quite indifferent about heading outside

Comment: Was there an anti-car-culture movement in 1955? (if so, it failed). I'm pretty sure this is an allegory to car culture.

Comment: Seems very closely related to "The Fun They Had," also by Asimov.

Comment: @user253751 There was a strong anti-car, then anti-jaywalking lobby in the US (where Asimov lived) in the '20s and '30s (his formative years). [Source.](https://marker.medium.com/the-invention-of-jaywalking-afd48f994c05)

Comment: I think Dickie's motivation changes with experience.  He's been taught that outside is dirt and disease but, once he's *been* outside, he sees that it's beautiful and interesting and isn't doing him any harm.

Comment: @user3819867 it's a shame we don't have an anti-jaydriving movement (that is, against the driving of cars on city streets)